# Is 死ぬ the only verb ending in -ぬ?

Tags: words, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plain verbs that end with ぬ other than 死ぬ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/plain-verbs-that-end-with-%e3%81%ac-other-than-%e6%ad%bb%e3%81%ac)

死ぬ{しぬ} is the only verb that I know that is ending in -ぬ.

So, are there any other verbs ending in -ぬ?

Answer (score 1):

I could find one other verb listed as `v5n` (class of "Godan verb nu") that didn't end with `死ぬ` in [Edict](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/edict.html): [`往{い}ぬ`](http://www.jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%BE%80%E3%81%AC+&eng=&dict=edict)/[`去{い}ぬ`](http://www.jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%8E%BB%E3%81%AC%20&eng=&dict=edict).